# Writing to windows log with VBScript for Windows Updates?

Tags: windows, vbscript

I am using [this sample script](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from Microsoft to do Windows Updates.  However, whenever an update is installed, I want to write it to a custom log.  Right now, I've tweaked the last part of the code as follows:

```
    For I = 0 to updatesToInstall.Count - 1
        WScript.Echo I + 1 & "> " & _
        updatesToInstall.Item(i).Title & _
        ": " & installationResult.GetUpdateResult(i).ResultCode 

        Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        addLog = "eventcreate /l Application /t Information /so Test-QA /id 74 /d Windows update added: " & updatesToInstall.Item(i).Title
        WshShell.Run addLog
    Next
End If
```

However, when updates were installed, nothing was added to the Windows Event Log.  What should I do in order to write this information to the log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`eventcreate` probably fails because you didn't add quotes around the log message. Change

```
addLog = "eventcreate /l Application /t Information /so Test-QA /id 74 /d Windows update added: " & updatesToInstall.Item(i).Title
```

into

```
addLog = "eventcreate /l Application /t Information /so Test-QA /id 74 " _
  & "/d ""Windows update added: " & updatesToInstall.Item(i).Title & """"
```

You can check the return code of commands run via the `Run` method like this:

```
rc = WshShell.Run(addLog)
If rc <> 0 Then
  WScript.Echo "Error: Command exited with return code " & rc
End If
```

To take a look at the command output prepend the command with `%COMSPEC% /k` and run it in a visible window:

```
addLog = "%COMSPEC% /k eventcreate ..."
rc = WshShell.Run(addLog, 1, False)
```

Since you're installing updates I suppose you already are running the script with admin privileges, correct?

Comment: Made the changes, and the error message didn't appear, so that's good.  However, the Windows Event Log has no record of the log I want recorded

Comment: Yes, I am.  However, your original answer was correct.  I had a bit of a typo, so that was completely on me.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

Why not just use the LogEvent method, it might do everything you need.

Read more at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176682.aspx

Comment: `LogEvent` does not allow for user-defined source names or event IDs.